# Take a List and an integer as input from user

Tags: python, list, input, split, integer

I want to take list and an integer as input from user.
I tried using split method in following way:

```
lst,n=input().split(",")
print(lst)
print(n)
```

Input:

```
[1,2,3,4],5
```

Output expected:

```
[1,2,3,4]
5
```

Comment: use this for your list input `lst = list(map(int, input("Enter the values with , between them: ").split(",")))`

Answer (score 2):

You could match either from `[...]` or match 1 or more digits using a pattern with an alternation

```
import re

pattern = r"\[[^][]*\]|\d+"
s = "[1,2,3,4],5"
print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['[1,2,3,4]', '5']
```

---

Or a bit more precise only matching digits optionally separated by a comma, spaces and more digits:

```
\[\s*\d+(?:\s*,\s*\d+)*\s*]|\d+
```

Answer (score 1):

To be able to write `lst,n = ...`, you need the input to be split only once, on the last comma. So, instead of `str.split`, you should use `str.rsplit(maxsplit=1)`.

Then, since the list is surrounded by `[` and `]` characters, you need to discard those before splitting the list.

Finally, since the input is made of characters but you want numbers, you should call `int` to convert the strings to numbers.

```py
def list_and_number(s):
    s,n = s.rsplit(',', maxsplit=1)
    n = int(n)
    lst = [int(x) for x in s.strip('[]').split(',')]
    return lst, n

lst, n = list_and_number(input())
print(lst)
print(n)

# INPUT
[1,2,3,4],5

# OUTPUT
[1, 2, 3, 4]
5
```

Comment: I'm restricted to use python 3.8 and removeprefix and removesuffix doesn't work on 3.8

Comment: @ShreyashKashid I have replaced `.removeprefix('[').removesuffix(']')` with `.strip('[]')`.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier if you just omitted the brackets and used extended iterable unpacking.

```
*lst, n = map(int, input().split(','))
```

This will give you `lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]`, and `n = 5` for the input `1,2,3,4,5`.

Note/caveat: an input of `1` will give you `lst = []` and `n = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give an external input to a program you can just define it as sys.argv

```
import sys

print("Give me the list")
lst = sys.argv[0]
print("Give me the number")
num = sys.argv[1]
```